# Svg rect not filling horizontal space

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm struggling with one of my SVGs where for now I'm just filling it with a solid grey rect. The rect fills fine vertically, but horizontally it's not filling the full space:

[image]

Here's a snippet from my html:

```
<div class="col-9 sh-input">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 100" width="100%" height="40px">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="100" fill="#333"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

To get the rect to actually fill the entire view, currently I need to change x to ~-100 & width to ~1200.

I've been through all stylings to see if anything there could be the cause, but no luck, and I'm not doing any custom styling on svgs at the moment. Also, as a long shot, since the svg width is defined in percent & height in pixels, I wondered if that could be a factor, but changing the svg width="475px" is still producing the same result.

So I'm a little stumped at the moment, especially since I've used almost this exact code in other parts of my application without the same issues. If anyone can point out what dumb mistake I'm making I'll be eternally grateful!

Comment: It's because you do not preserve the aspect ratio. If you don't mind deformation you may add `preserveAspectRatio ="none"` to the svg element.

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta! I knew it would be something simple and stupid. That's working fine now. Do you want to post that as the answer and I'll mark as accepted?